# Why only one accessor of a property is allowed to have access modifier in c#?

Tags: c#

While reading about properties in c# i came to know that only one accessor of a property can have access modifier such as

> private or protected

for example

```
 public int mbox_ival
    {
        get{
            return m_ival;
        }
       protected set {

            m_ival = value;
        }

    }
```

Now if i want to restrict both the properties to be protected, i came to know that it is not allowed.In **c# specification** also it is said that only one accessor can have access modifier. I am unable to understand the reason behind this.I am new to c# can someone please help.

Comment: Just consider the modifier on the setter to be an override of the property's modifier. They are both public unless you override one of them. Overriding both would not make sense.

Answer (score 10):

Both protected:

```
protected int mbox_ival {
    get { return m_ival; }
    set { m_ival = value; }
}
```

The reason you can only have one is that you have the property's access modifier.

That modifier is the default modifier.  Modifying both just means  that you should "hoist" the  more permissive one.

For example:

```
public int mbox_ival {
    protected get { return m_ival; }
    private set { m_ival = value; }
}
```

Makes no sense, because the property isn't actually public. It's at best protected.  So you should do this instead:

```
protected int mbox_ival {
    get { return m_ival; }
    private set { m_ival = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because if you don't specify the access modifier before the 'get' or the 'set', they will both have the access modifier that you set on the property. It doesn't make sense to make the property public, if you're going to overwrite both the 'get' and the 'set' to be protected. You might just as well set the property to 'protected' in the first place.